# Thread safety & atomicity of java semaphore

Tags: java, thread-safety, semaphore, atomic

How are they achieved? I have seen the code of that class and it doesn't look like any kind of synchronisation mechanisms are used to ensure thread safety or atomicity of function calls.

I am referring to the class `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`

edit : Please understand it is no way a bug report or non-confidence in java technology. Rather, a request to let me understand.

Comment: Noticed the `class Sync extends AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`?

Comment: `Semaphore` uses an [`AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.html) (as @assylias notes, I just thought I'd link to the documentation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Introduction**

In a broader *lens*, the question becomes how are any locking mechanisms achieving thread safety. Since this question has a few parts to it, I will step through it step by step.

**Compare-and-Swap (CAS)**

[Compare-and-Swap (CAS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) is an [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability) instruction at machine-level and an atomic operation at a programmatic level. Now, in your specific semaphore question, they utilize this technique while accessing a permit from a semaphore.

1. Grab the *current value*
2. Calculate the *new value*
3. Perform a **CAS** operation by passing in the *current value* and the *new value*, seeing if the value at that memory access is the current value and swap it with the new. If it does hold the current value we have noted, the value is stored at the memory location and it returns true. If it finds a different value than our expected current value, it will not modify the memory location and return false.

**AbstractQueuedSynchronizer**

The [AbstractQueuedSynchronizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.html) class is an implemented class to handle synchronization while acquiring permits. The implementation creates a [FIFO queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) (Although there are different types of queues that can be used) and utilizes **park/unpark** techniques to deal with the thread running state.

**Park/Unpark**

A thread will **park** when there are no available permits in the semaphore. Conversely, the thread will **unpark** once a permit has become available (assuming you are using the FIFO implementation the first will **unpark**) and attempt a **CAS** operation to acquire the permit. If it fails, it will **park** and the process repeats.

**Conclusion**

These concepts working together utilize atomicity through machine-level instructions and programmatic operations to ensure permits/locks are only acquired by a single thread at a time thus, limiting thread access to blocks of logic to the desired amount.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to understand that is by looking at `nonfairTryAcquireShared()`:

```
final int nonfairTryAcquireShared(int acquires) {
        for (;;) {
            int available = getState();
            int remaining = available - acquires;
            if (remaining < 0 ||
                compareAndSetState(available, remaining))
                return remaining;
        }
    }
```

So, we busy-loop trying to acquire the state, then we're trying to take it.

Most interesting part is in `compareAndSetState()`

```
protected final boolean compareAndSetState(int expect, int update) {
    // See below for intrinsics setup to support this
    return unsafe.compareAndSwapInt(this, stateOffset, expect, update);
}
```

`compareAndSwapInt` is a native function, that guarantees atomicity, and thus - synchronization, in our case.